# How to talk to independent docker container by name?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two distinct `docker` containers, independent from each other.

Now I want to talk from one to the other. Is that only possible by IP:PORT? Or even by application name?

This is the container I want to talk to:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  my-container:
    ...
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    extra_hosts:
        - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Is there a way that another container could simply connect to `http://my-container`? Or would I always have to go the way injecting the host network ip with `extra_hosts` to both containers, and then connect with `http://host.docker.internal`?

Sidenote: all my containers are on the same default docker bridge network.

Comment: they need to be in the same network

Comment: ...and that network needs to _not_ be the "default bridge network".  If you're running in Compose, it automatically creates a "user-defined bridge network" named `default`.

Comment: Okay, and how could I merge both "user-defined bridge networks" named default? Or are they already both in the same "default" bridge network if I didn't set any?

Comment: I've linked this question to two others that answer the question.  The "communicate via hostname" question discusses manually setting up the Docker network; "communication between projects" talks about configuring two Compose files to talk to each other.

Comment: (The `default` network is scoped to a specific Compose project, but you can configure one project's `default` network to actually be the other's.)